# How to remove ErrorViewModel when using dotnet core with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

If ErrorViewModel is removed from my project, it won't run, failing at `app.UseMvc()` with the error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
>   'DocumentGenerationService.Models.ErrorViewModel' from assembly 'DocumentGenerationService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'

It is a dotnet core 2.2 application with mvc. I've removed everything that is unnecessary to the application, which includes all the views, as this is a webapi project.

Why can't I remove ErrorViewModel from the project? It's making me sad.

For reference, here's how the startup class looks:

```
public class Startup
    {
        ...

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddSignalR();

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
           ...

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the ErrorViewModel class and have the project run? Or an explanation of why it isn't possible?

Thanks StackOverflowers!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the following solution worked for me:

1. Remove all the ErrorViewModel related files like Controllers, Views, etc...
2. Close the Visual Studio if it's open
3. Go to the source directory and remove `obj` and `bin` directories
4. Open the project with Visual Studio and run it

Now it should work as a normal WebApi project.

Answer (score 1):

First welcome to the Stack Overflow community.

Now after removing the `ErrorViewModel` from models folder you need to do following things to remove the `ErrorViewModel` related codes:

- Delete the `Error` method from `HomeController`
- Delete `Error.cshtml` file from `Views/Shared` folder
- Now check `_ViewImports` file in the `Views` folder. If there is any red line starting with `@using` then please remove this line.

Now build the solution and run again. Hope it will run now gracefully.

Comment: Thanks @TanvirArjel. I've already removed all of that stuff. There is no HomeController (only one that I need) and no Views at all. The only reason mvc is being used is for routing.