# New MVC Created A CS file called "errorviewmodel.cs" In Models Folder. I am Confused On Naming Convention

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a new project in C# using dotnet new mvc. I noticed under my models folder a file called **ErrorViewModel.cs**.  I was wondering why its called that as it looks like its for something specific like errors or some other such thing.

Would it be safe to change the file name to something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove ErrorViewModel when using dotnet core with MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312357/how-to-remove-errorviewmodel-when-using-dotnet-core-with-mvc) or possibly https://stackoverflow.com/q/61766956/585968

Comment: Honestly no, I am wanting to figure out what that file does specifically. I tried googling it, but doing a google search with the word"error" brings up too much info not relevant to what I want to know.

Comment: The name is pretty self-explanatory and the links explain what happens if you _"change the file name to something else"_.   I wouldn't Google _"error"_ but rather something like _"asp.net mvc ErrorViewModel.cs."_

Comment: thank you , that google search helped a lot more than "errorviewmodel". I got this as a result which answers my question.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: That's great you found a result.  Don't forget _you_ can post that as an _answer_ (below) for your own question possibly earning you reputation.  :)

Comment: Thank you for that I didn't even think to do that I'm still pretty new to programming only been at it for about 4 months.

Comment: No problem.  Keep at it, programming is awesome, you'll love it :)

Answer (score 0):

This link will answer my own question.
Its basically there to handle errors such as 404 and other such things.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0